# Django: Pitfalls when setting AUTO_COMMIT = OFF for MySQL innoDB?

Tags: mysql, django

I am upgrading Django 1.5 to Django 1.10. As part of that process I want to set:

```
AUTO_COMMIT = OFF
```

for my MySQL innoDB database. Without this, 1.10 doesn't seem to give me the level of control that I need. For example, within one request, I need to be able to execute a query, do a rollback (in case it went wrong), execute another query, and then commit that. Then continue on to do something non-database related else before returning.

My question is, what are the pitfalls? Django recommends not turning auto_commit off, but why?

Remembering to commit at the end of each request is no problem. I'm more concerned that the MySQL DB could get into some weird state. Locks or excessive space usage or or??

Edit: I am looking for specific examples of things that can go wrong with auto_commit=off, not the general arm-waving Django info, which I have read, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the Django 1.9 docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/), with my bold emphasis added:

> Django’s default behavior is to run in autocommit mode. Each query is immediately committed to the database, unless a transaction is active. [...]
>
> Django uses transactions or savepoints automatically **to guarantee the integrity of ORM operations that require multiple queries**, especially `delete()` and `update()` queries.
>
> When autocommit is turned on and no transaction is active, each SQL query gets wrapped in its own transaction. In other words, not only does each such query start a transaction, but the transaction also gets automatically committed or rolled back, depending on whether the query succeeded. [...]
>
> To avoid this, you can deactivate the transaction management, but it isn’t recommended. [...]
>
> You can totally disable Django’s transaction management for a given database by setting `AUTOCOMMIT` to `False` in its configuration. If you do this, Django won’t enable autocommit, and won’t perform any commits. You’ll get the regular behavior of the underlying database library.
>
> **This requires you to commit explicitly every transaction, even those started by Django or by third-party libraries**. Thus, **this is best used in situations where you want to run your own transaction-controlling middleware** or do something really strange.

In short, it looks like if you set `autocommit` to off, then you not only have to take care of the queries that *your* client code has initiated, but also the queries that are being executed *internally* by the framework, which you may not know about.

In addition, the framework is trying to guarantee the integrity of the system as it operates and it'll be better to let it do its work for you rather than to fill your code with corner-cases to do the handling yourself. That will be error-prone in the best case, and a potential maintenance nightmare in the long-run.

> I'm more concerned that the MySQL DB could get into some weird state.

Your solution to this concern seems to actually make it *more* likely that you'll run into the problem you're trying to prevent.

Comment: I have read this before and none of it is very specific. What queries are the Django framework performing, which might not be committed? Which ORM operations do I need to worry about? Maybe these things are not issues in my case. The site is working fine now with auto_commit = off, but I am worried about special cases or issues that can build up over time. What, specifically, might they be...

Comment: @user984003 The documentation is enough to give you a general warning as to why they don't recommend certain things, and it's specific enough to be useful. There's no way to know what queries django may be using internally without stepping through the code, b/c it depends on what your app is doing. If you really want to know the implementation details, then you'll need to look at django's code directly.